# AWS elasticbeanstalk automating deletion of logs published to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, logrotate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have enabled publishing of logs from AWS elasticbeanstalk to AWS S3 by following these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

This is working fine. My question is how do I automate the deletion of old logs from S3, say over one week old? Ideally I'd like a way to configure this within AWS but I can't find this option.  I have considered using logrotate but was wondering if there is a better way. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually discovered how to do this. You can create an S3 Lifecycle rule to delete particular files or all files in a folder more than N days old. Note: you can also archive instead of delete or archive for a while before deleting, among other things- it's a great feature.

[image: How to add a S3 bucket LifeCycle rule]

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html
and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-console.html